# How to check if the text from a textbox is a number?

Tags: java, swing, textbox

So i have the following window that has a textbox and a button.

```
public class Menu extends JFrame {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final int WIDTH = 225;
        private static final int HEIGHT = 270;
        private static final int SCALE = 1;  
        private JTextField txtGenerationSize;
        public Menu(String title){
            setSize(450, 358);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
            setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
            setResizable(false);
            this.pack();
            setVisible(true);
            setTitle(title);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

            JPanel MenuPanel = new JPanel();
            getContentPane().add(MenuPanel, "name_36840921662905");
            MenuPanel.setLayout(null);

            JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Evolve!");
            lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
            lblTitle.setBounds(76, 21, 79, 14);
            MenuPanel.add(lblTitle);

            JLabel lblGenerationSize = new JLabel("Generation Size");
            lblGenerationSize.setBounds(10, 108, 79, 14);
            MenuPanel.add(lblGenerationSize);

            txtGenerationSize = new JTextField();
            txtGenerationSize.setBounds(99, 105, 56, 20);
            MenuPanel.add(txtGenerationSize);
            txtGenerationSize.setColumns(10);

            JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start generation");
            btnStart.setBounds(10, 208, 199, 23);
            MenuPanel.add(btnStart);


        }
    }
```

When they click the button i want to check if what they introduced in the textbox is a number

How can i do that?

Comment: What type of number, `int`, `double`, etc.? Are you going to be using the value? Does it need to be big?

Comment: `Integer.parse` or `NumberFormat.parse`?

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify